# Certificate Authority - certificate revocation process

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

When Certificate Authority revoke digital certificate, how browser knows that this certificate is not validate.

Does browser check revocation list every time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browser does not know about every certificate CA might have revoked. But when it comes across a certificate that it has to validate (i.e. SSL certificate) then it will validate it.

When browser has to validate the certificate it will build certificate chain up to a trusted root CA and the for each element in the chain it will check revocation list. List of trusted root authorities is bundled with the browser.

Revocation list could be cached as it has expiration date in it (not_after). 
If there is link to OCSP in the certificate then browser could (based on its settings) use OCSP instead of CRL to check validity of the certificate.